# How to persist reference from child to parent in OneToMany relation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

### Core question

How can I **properly** persist a reference from child to parent in a OneToMany relation in hibernate.

---

### Explanation

I have implemented the following example of [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) 
 
[Example 119](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) states exactly my problem. I'll copy and explain the situation in this question just for convenience purposes:

So we have two objects:
A Person (object 1) that has multiple Phones (object 2) (one to many bidirectional relationship).

This is how they can be initialized and persisted:

```
Person person = new Person();
Phone phone1 = new Phone( "123-456-7890" );
Phone phone2 = new Phone( "321-654-0987" );

person.addPhone( phone1 );
person.addPhone( phone2 );
entityManager.persist( person );
entityManager.flush();
```

And Hibernate will convert this to sql as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Phone
       ( number, person_id, id )
VALUES ( '123-456-7890', NULL, 2 )

INSERT INTO Phone
       ( number, person_id, id )
VALUES ( '321-654-0987', NULL, 3 )
```

The problem is the 'NULL' values that get inserted at the column where person_id should be inserted. So is there a way for hibernate to be aware of the OneToMany relationship and insert the Id from its parent in the reference column (person_id in this case)?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you follow that example exactly of divert somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I am aware of that solution, but that doesn't seem quite a proper way to fix it since you will first add the phone objects to the person and then you'll add the person object to the phones again... This is very  much counter intuitive to me for proper development.

Comment: I diverted but my results are the same as in the example, persisting the objects isn't the problem, just the way the reference is stored in the db doesn't seem quite efficient (why put NULL in place of the person_id instead of grabbing the person_id from the parent object??) I highly assume Hibernate has a fix for this but I am not able to find it yet.

Comment: yes it is somewhat counter intuitive but that's the way it is when `Phone` is the owning side (I deleted the comment since that isn't be the case in the example). You could call `phone.setPerson(this)` in `addPhone(Phone phone)` though.

Comment: @Thomas I am afraid that is the only way to do it, but I very much hope there is a better way because this is quite disappointing from Hibernate. And I don't have much experience in Hibernate so that is why I hope some more experienced hibernate developer can tell me how things really are and perhaps how to make it work properly or explain why it is not possible.

Comment: the other way to do it would be to use a join table like the unidirectional examples do (Person_Phone). When `Phone` is the owning side there are actually very good reasons to do it that way and I doubt there's another approach that makes handling those situations more intuitive while being stable at the same time (i.e. the approach would have to work with quite a many different possible setups).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114847/discussion-between-ben-and-thomas).